# AWS Api Gateway Proxy modifying response

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I have a AWS Api Gateway.

My goal is to act as a proxy for an existing restful api, but I need to handle the restful api response and do some modifications before returning the enhanced response.

I set the api gateway as proxy, but it doesn't allow me to get the response and modify it(actually, it does, but only to modify the status code)

I know I can create a lambda, execute it from the API Gateway, get the request, create a new request to the restful api, get the response, modify it and return a new response, but that's what I want to avoid.

Any idea?

Comment: I guess my main questions is what level of response manipulation are you trying to achieve and have you looked into the `Integration Response Mapping Templates`?

Comment: It's kind of complex. Actually, I'll be using third party services(APIs) to modify the response, that's why I was thinking on a lambda to do this